# Using different polysaccharides for coagulation

Tags: biochemistry

Would a particular type of polysaccharide be better at coagulation than another? For example, would the presence of cellulose in a bio-coagulant be more effective at coagulation than the presence of starch or glycogen? I would like to know as I am doing an experiment about it and since nobody has done this before, I don't know whether having a higher concentration or ratio of a certain polysaccharide in a bio-coagulant compared to other polysaccharides will have an effect on coagulation efficiency?